# post differences in php

Tags: php, html

I am using some code to get the input values from an html form, and I was wondering the differences between using:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'residence');
```

instead of: `$_POST['residence']`

For some of the code, I need to read in an array of data (check box options) and the $_POST method seems to do the job instead of filter_input.

Thank you!

Comment: One filters, the other doesn't.

Comment: Your *"instead of: $_POST['residence']"* is unclear. Are you trying to filter that using the filter also? You'd need to loop it in a `foreach` if you're trying to filter an array.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I think I am just confused what the filter_input method does

Comment: $_POST should be used when capturing form inputs. I've never even considered using the other method. You would use that if you wanted to filter out, for example, HTML special characters from an input. You aren't doing any filtering, so why bother. Here are filters that can be passed for sanitation [PHP filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: Far as I know, that method filters "user" input rather than radios/checkboxes that stand to have preset values. Is this XSS injection related?

Comment: @acaputo Thank you very much. I was taught to use the filter_input method, but never explained the true differences. Thanks again

Comment: @datasci glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

If your $_POST contains an array value:

```
<?php
$_POST  = array(
    'var' => array('more', 'than', 'one', 'values')
);
?>
```

you should use FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY option:

```
<?php
var_dump(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'var', FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY));
?>
```

Otherwise it returns false.

(from: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)